# persistence.xml different transaction-type attributes

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jta, persistence.xml

In the persistence.xml JPA configuration file, you can have a line like:

```
<persistence-unit name="com.nz_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
```

or sometimes:

```
<persistence-unit name="com.nz_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type=”RESOURCE_LOCAL”>
```

**My question is:**

What is the difference between `transaction-type="JTA"` and `transaction-type=”RESOURCE_LOCAL”` ?

I also noticed some persistence.xml files with the transaction-type missing. Is it correct?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

### Defaults

Default to **JTA** in a JavaEE environment and to **RESOURCE_LOCAL** in a JavaSE environment.

### RESOURCE_LOCAL

With `<persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">` you are responsible for `EntityManager` (`PersistenceContext/Cache`) creating and tracking

- You must use the `EntityManagerFactory` to get an `EntityManager`
- The resulting `EntityManager` instance is a `PersistenceContext/Cache`
  An `EntityManagerFactory` can be injected via the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation only (not `@PersistenceContext`)
- You are not allowed to use `@PersistenceContext` to refer to a unit of type `RESOURCE_LOCAL`
- You must use the `EntityTransaction` API to begin/commit around every call to your `EntityManger`
- Calling `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` twice results in two separate `EntityManager` instances and therefor two separate `PersistenceContexts/Caches`.
- It is almost never a good idea to have more than one instance of an `EntityManager` in use (don't create a second one unless you've destroyed the first)

### JTA

With `<persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA">` the container will do `EntityManager` (`PersistenceContext/Cache`) creating and tracking.

- You cannot use the `EntityManagerFactory` to get an `EntityManager`
- You can only get an `EntityManager` supplied by the container
- An `EntityManager` can be injected via the `@PersistenceContext` annotation only (not `@PersistenceUnit`)
- You are not allowed to use `@PersistenceUnit` to refer to a unit of type JTA
- The `EntityManager` given by the container is a reference to the `PersistenceContext/Cache` associated with a JTA Transaction.
- If no JTA transaction is in progress, the `EntityManager` cannot be used because there is no `PersistenceContext/Cache`.
- Everyone with an `EntityManager` reference to the same unit in the same transaction will automatically have a reference to the same `PersistenceContext/Cache`
- The `PersistenceContext/Cache` is flushed and cleared at JTA commit time

Comment: I think you made a little mistake with the titles of the two lists: maybe you shuffled them?

Comment: and clearly you can use JTA in a JavaSE environment too, and get the EM yourself from the EMF ... such as when using a stand-alone JTA provider. Perhaps your lists refer to JavaSE and JavaEE as opposed to JTA and RESOURCE_LOCAL

Comment: "It is almost never a good idea to have more than one instance of an EntityManager in use" -- Is this your opinion? It's often necessary to have multiple open EntityManagers open in a concurrent application. In general, a very good answer.

Comment: I used RESOURCE_LOCAL without having the need to begin and end transactions myself. I think RESOURCE_LOCAL is more like "I wan to test this database using local test memory" which is very helpful for JUnit testing.

Comment: With RESOURCE_LOCAL, may I use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() instead of @PersistenceUnit to get an EMF?

Comment: @Zyl: what I understand you can but you are creating EMF completely out of the container management capabilities.
That means that you will need to have jdbc driver on application class path and connection to database is needed to be specified via properties of PU. I mean <jta-data-source> tag won't be reflected as you connect "directly" to database.

Comment: I don't agree with statement that "You are not allowed to use @PersistenceUnit to refer to a unit of type JTA". I think that you can easily do so and you can use method emf.createEntityManager() to get entity manager. And you can use the argument of type SynchronizationType to define if current transaction should be joined immediately or you will join it yourself when calling em.joinTransaction() method

Comment: @ha9u63ar How would I inject my EntityManager using PersistenceContext annotation and LocalResource in my unit test? Do you have an example?

Comment: You may take a look at the source of the answer with addtional informations and short example:
http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html

Comment: I have using tomcat as the web server for deploying my application. Should i use "JTA" or "RESOURCE_LOCAL" ?