# Persistence.XML JavaEE with EJB and Intellij

Tags: java, xml, jpa, intellij-idea, glassfish

i'm trying to configurate a JavaEE project with IntelliJ IDEA.

my configuration :

- IDE Intellij (Jetbrains)
- Glassfish (EJB Container)
- JPA entities (Hibernate provider)
- Database with WAMP (configured in persistence.xml)

Unfortunately, when i launch my project, a 404 page is displaying :
 EJBTransactionRolledbackException.

i don't understand this exception or this problem...maybe it's my file persistence.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/supbartering" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and i use it with :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
private EntityManager mEntityManager;
```

It's the first time i 'm using Intellij with JEE project and GlassFish server, but i can't achieve the good configuration.

Comment: can you post your full  exception?

Comment: Have you tested with `transaction-type="JTA"` instead of "JPA"? Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713599/javax-ejb-ejbexception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-retrieve-entit?lq=1

Comment: @Baderous, it's already JTA  :s ...Mistake =).

Comment: why use Hibernate specific connection properties when there are JPA standard ones? makes no sense. If using JTA then need a jtaDataSource not connectionURL/user/password

Comment: @NeilStockton Thank you. Can you post an explain response with JTA and jtaDataSource ?? i don't know where i must put URL,user, password...and jtaDataSource

Answer (score 1):

You are using Hibernate specific "local datasource" properties, yet you claim to want to use JTA transactions. That is inconsistent. See section 8.2.1.2 of the JPA spec

> The transaction-type attribute is used to specify whether the entity
>   managers provided by the entity manager factory for the persistence
>   unit must be JTA entity managers or resource-local entity managers.
>   The value of this element is JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL. A transaction-type
>   of JTA assumes that a JTA data source will be provided—either as
>   specified by the jta-data-source element or provided by the container.
>   In general, in Java EE environments, a transaction-type of
>   RESOURCE_LOCAL assumes that a non-JTA datasource will be provided. In
>   a Java EE environment, if this element is not specified, the default
>   is JTA. In a Java SE environment, if this element is not specified,
>   the default is RESOURCE_LOCAL.

So you either use JTA, define your JTA data source externally, and specify the "jtaDataSource" in persistence.xml (and remove the url/user/password/driver), OR you use RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions and define the data source via connection URL/user/password/driver properties (and use the standard javax.persistence properties like [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/emf.html#Standard_JPA_Properties) shows).

Comment: How can i create Local datasource in IntelliJ IDEA ? ty.