# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am creating Spring boot application with **2 different datasources**. I have created configuration files for separate DB. Entities are in different package and Models are in different package for each database. When I run

> mvn clean install

it creates database properly and all tables as well. But is always fails while creating repository. Below I am providing all necessary details:

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name= nyota-plateform
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database= MYSQL
spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy= org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl


spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB1?useUnicode=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= *
spring.datasource.password= *
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-idle= 10000

authdb.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
authdb.datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB2?useUnicode=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
authdb.datasource.username= *
authdb.datasource.password= *
authdb.datasource.dbcp2.max-idle= 10000
```

Db1 configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.demo.repo.db1" })
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.test.demo.model.db1").persistenceUnit("main").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

DB2 configuration:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.demo.repo.db2" })
    public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authdb.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory2")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.test.demo.model.db2").persistenceUnit("main").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory2") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Db2 Model

```
@Entity
public class AuthUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String role;

    @Column
    private String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


    public AuthUser(String name, String username, String password, String role) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String email) {
        this.username = email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AuthUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AuthUser, Long> {

    public AuthUser findByUsernameAndPassword(String email,String password);
}
```

Now error Log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authUserRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.test.demo.model.auth.AuthUser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.test.demo.Demo.main(Demo.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone help on this? What parameter I am missing or what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot - Not an managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-an-managed-type)

Comment: Very nice question, i was also stuck in same condition

Comment: @f1sh I am not sure it is same or not, but I tried **ComponentScan , EntityScan, Component** as well. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246104/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type!

Comment: @singh09iet I am using **2 datasources** and rest of them are having only **one datasource**. Therefore **my question is different**. Single datasource is working fine, no problem at all. I have seen all other option available in past two  days but none of them solves my problem.

Comment: This exception happens when the component Scanner did not scan your @Entity class. Check if it scans your package.

Comment: Interesting but spring should throw the property not found exception in your repository class `findByUsernameAndPassword(String email,String password);` email is not in your bean and it should eventually fail refer [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions). Is it the all configuration are we missing anything.

Comment: @mallikarjun **email** doesn't make any change here. main class was missing which I have updated. There is nothing else we have missed from configuration.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary please look at the configuration sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817120/spring-jpa-multiple-persistence-units-injecting-entitymanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my problem, All I need to do is to update following line in Database configuration file.

From :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.demo.repo.db1" })
```

To :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", basePackages = { "com.test.demo.repo.db1" })
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using different datasources. Using the `@Qualifier` annotation solved it for me. In the configurations you could annotate your Beans with `@Qualifier("DB1")` and use them in your Repository with `@Transactional(transactionManager="DB1")`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please remove @primary annotation from one data source