# Java JPA Illegal Argument Exception - NamedQuery of name: xyz not found

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, dao

I am trying to get a user based on their ID using this named query, however I keep getting an illegal argument exception. I've been looking at this code for awhile. Hopefully someone may catch something I might've missed.
This is my ORM

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYUSER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByUserid", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.userid = :userid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByName", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByPassword", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.password = :password"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByEmail", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.email = :email"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByTel", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.tel = :tel"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByAddress", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.address = :address"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findBySecqn", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.secqn = :secqn"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findBySecans", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.secans = :secans")})
public class Myuser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USERID")
private Integer userid;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Column(name = "TEL")
private Integer tel;
@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;
@Column(name = "SECQN")
private String secqn;
@Column(name = "SECANS")
private String secans;

public Myuser() {
}

public Myuser(Integer userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public Integer getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Integer getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(Integer tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getSecqn() {
    return secqn;
}

public void setSecqn(String secqn) {
    this.secqn = secqn;
}

public String getSecans() {
    return secans;
}

public void setSecans(String secans) {
    this.secans = secans;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (userid != null ? userid.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Myuser)) {
        return false;
    }
    Myuser other = (Myuser) object;
    if ((this.userid == null && other.userid != null) || (this.userid != null && !this.userid.equals(other.userid))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ejbentity.Myuser[ userid=" + userid + " ]";
}

}
```

This is my user facade

```
@Stateless
public class MyuserFacade implements MyuserFacadeRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBServer-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;


protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public MyuserFacade() {
    //super(Myuser.class);
}

@Override
public Myuser getUser(int userID) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser =   (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByUserid").setParameter("userid", userID).getResultList();
    return aUser;
}
}
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="EJBEntityPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<!--<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>-->
<class>ejbentity.Myuser</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EA"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
    </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error Log is given below:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy266.getUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Myuser.findByUserid not found.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:355)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:522)
at stateless.MyuserFacade.getUser(MyuserFacade.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
... 19 more
Java Result: 1
```

[image: File Structure]

Comment: Can you show your stacktrace? where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: @Anmol I'll place my stacktrace in the edit. It appears in aUser = (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByUserid").setParameter("userid", userID).getResultList();

Answer (score 6):

We got the same error and it was because the entities were missing in persistence.xml

Answer (score 4):

Actual error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Myuser.findByUserid not found.
```

Happens from:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByUserid", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m WHERE m.userid = :userid"),
```

**UPDATE:**
From your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="EJBEntityPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Here you are using `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"`. So if you use it, then you are responsible for EntityManager.
Then you must have to follow ([JPA Concepts: JPA 101](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html))

1. You must use the `EntityManagerFactory` to get an `EntityManager`
2. The resulting `EntityManager` instance is a `PersistenceContext/Cache`
3. An `EntityManagerFactory` can be injected via the `@PersistenceUnit`
   annotation only (not `@PersistenceContext`)
4. You are not allowed to use `@PersistenceContext` to refer to a unit of
   type `RESOURCE_LOCAL`
5. You must use the `EntityTransaction API` to begin/commit around every
   call to your `EntityManger`
6. Calling `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` twice results in
   two separate EntityManager instances and therefor two separate
   `PersistenceContexts/Caches`.
7. It is almost never a good idea to have more than one instance of an
   `EntityManager` in use (don't create a second one unless you've
   destroyed the first)

### **Solution:**

This is an [example](http://www.madbit.org/blog/programming/836/persistence-with-jpa2-resource_local-vs-jta/#sthash.F4v9grFL.hOAmIsPx.dpbs). you can follow the tutorial if you want to use `RESOURCE_LOCAL`.

Related Link:

1. [DON'T USE JPA'S RESOURCE_LOCAL ON THE SERVER](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/don_t_use_jpa_s)
2. [Persistence unit as RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962525/persistence-unit-as-resource-local-or-jta)
3. [persistence.xml different transaction-type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331024/persistence-xml-different-transaction-type-attributes)

Comment: Sorry, I tried your way but it still gave me an Injection Exception.

Comment: @JianYA I have updated the answer with some suggestions and example. Would you please check?

Comment: I'm looking through them now. My EntityManager is autogenerated by Netbeans though. In the first link you gave me, they reference an account.class, where would that be in terms of my code?

Comment: I think it will be better to use JTA. Because you don't need more attention for EntityManager on that case. Please try with JTA and keep me updated

Answer (score 2):

In your persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="EJBEntityPU"
```

but in your MyuserFacade you use:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBServer-ejbPU")
```

You should change that to:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBEntityPU")
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have class ejbentity.Myuser in your persistence.xml. The class actually lives in a package structure consisting of one directory called "ejbentity"? The stacktrace suggests that your Myuser class with the NamedQuery annotations is not being found, which would be explained if your package structure is not being loaded as you expect.

Comment: Yes. Myuser lives in a package called ejbentity. However, the package is loaded in the import ejbentity.Myuser; in the MyuserFacade.java. What suggestion do you have for this ? I'm not very familiar sorry.

Comment: Can you explain the directory structure where your "ejbentity" directory is? The more typical Java package structure would be a series of nested directories starting with a top level domain like "com" or "org".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that transaction-type has anything to do with @NamedQuery annotation.

This error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Myuser.findAll not found.
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:355)

looks like an EclipseLink bug. Which version are you using ?