# Unrecognized JPA persistence.xml XSD version : `` - hibernate, java ee and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, java-ee-7, hibernate-entitymanager

The issue is appearing when trying to make entityManager with entitiManagerFactory.
Application is running inside docker container and postgresql database is on localhost of the machine (not inside docker).

my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<!-- Define persistence unit -->
<persistence-unit name="mypersistenceunit">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>some.path.SimplifiedUserGroup</class>
    <class>some.path.UserSettings</class>
    <class>some.path.UserGroupSettings</class>
    <class>some.path.UserGroup</class>
    <class>some.path.AppUser</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/localdatabase" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and the repository class:

```
public List<SimplifiedUserGroup> findAll() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mypersistenceunit");
    entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery("UserGroup.findAll", SimplifiedUserGroup.class).getResultList();
}
```

there is an error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
```

and then:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized JPA persistence.xml XSD version : ``
```

I tried several tutorials and read stackoverflow topics but nothing helps me - I tried with  but didn't help. The same with versions 2.0, 2.1, 2.2. 
I have such dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

It would be great if I could create an entityManager and then connect to database (on localhost) and perform some queries...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **PersistenceException** :

If you use the `EntityManagerFactory` in a JavaEE environment you need to define the **transaction-type** to `RESOURCE_LOCAL` in your *persistence.xml* :

```
<persistence-unit name="mypersistenceunit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

For more informations about the `EntityManager` and difference beetween transaction-type `JTA` and `RESOURCE_LOCAL` in the *persistence.xml* see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331863/9945960).

---

## **Unrecognized JPA persistence.xml XSD version** :

In your ***persistence.xml*** :

1. I dont see the **persistence enclosing tag** `</persistence>` after `</persistence-unit>` at the end.
2. You are using an **old URL** for the **XSD Schema Location**, change your `<persistence ... >` to :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
```

Informations from [**Oracle**](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html) :

> Starting with the 2.1 version, the Java Persistence API Schemas share the namespace, `http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/`. Previous versions used the namespace `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/`.