# Concurrency errors when using Spring Transaction management in Tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-transactions, hibernate-entitymanager

I am currently working on retrofitting Spring-based declarative transactions to a legacy application.
The application is deployed on Tomcat and uses JPA/Hibernate to access a PostgreSQL database, and a homegrown web framework
(so switching e.g. to Spring Boot is at this time not an option).

My problem is that after changing all DAOs to use an injected EntityManager, everything works when there is only a single user,
but with multiple users, I get exceptions that indicate concurrency problems:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.releaseResources(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.afterTransaction(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.afterTransaction(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.afterCompletion(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1054) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
```

and

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non thread safe access to session
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1394) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
```

This is the superclass all DAOs inherit from to get their `EntityManager` instance:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao {
    
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected AbstractDao() {
    }
    
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    @Scope("request") // just an experiment, should not be necessary AFAIK
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

This is the persistence configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my.package");
        
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager initTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactory());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here is the `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="de.lexcom.agroparts.persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">     
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp</non-jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the configuration in `web.xml` seems to be exactly what is needed to support the request scope, according to [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration) - I have tried configuring either a `RequestContextListener` or a `RequestContextFilter`, and can confirm via debugger that they are called, but neither seems to have an effect.

My understanding, according to [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional) is that the `@PersistenceConfig` annotation should
provide a proxy which forwards calls to a request-scoped entity manager instance that is set up by the `RequestContextListener` or `RequestContextFilter`.
For some reason, that doesn't seem to be working and instead every request goes to the same entity manager (or at least the same Hibernate session).

Or is the problem the `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` in the `persistence.xml`?
According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331024/persistence-xml-different-transaction-type-attributes)
it sounds like I have to use `transaction-type="JTA"` to use `@PersistenceContext` and have multiple `EntityManager` instances,
but that seems to be copied verbatim from [the TomEE documentation](https://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html)
(a JEE container), and it is contradicted [this article](https://by%20https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/)
which says that "by default, Spring applications use RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions".

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need a per request EntityManager? did you tried to remove the scope so you EntityManager is global ?

Comment: @Isukthar as far as I understand it, I *am* effectively getting a global EntityManager, and that is the problem because EntityManager instances are not threadsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper exception indicates that you are using the same Hibernate Session in multiple threads concurrently.

In Tomcat any servlet request is handled in a separate thread, so when you are on Spring it injects a special proxy instead of a simple EntityManager (see [SharedEntityManagerCreator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.java)). This proxy will automatically either reuse the existing `EntityManager` or create a new one depending on the current transaction (which is again thread-scoped).

`EntityManager` itself represent persistence context which is **by default bound to a particular transaction**. But in your code you use extended-scoped persistence context which can be used across multiple transactions.

```java
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
  this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

This seems to be a culprit of your case: with one user you have one thread and no data races, with multiple ones you `EntityManager` is accessed in racy way resulting in `CME`.

To fix the issue rewrite your code as:

```java
public abstract class AbstractDao {
    
  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  protected AbstractDao() {
  }
}
```

Also as soon as your are using `@EnableTransactionManagement` I'd suggest to rid `persistence.xml` in favor of Java config. See the example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring).

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much for the solution and the detailed explanation. Too bad this wasn't explained in any of the other places I looked. The Javadoc of PersistenceContextType also doesn't say anything about the implications.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt you are welcome. Apart from my own experience I've found one of the clues on Baeldung :D See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context